# Como ler os últimos 3 caracteres de um char sem tamanho definido

Tags: c

Tenho uma aplicação em C onde preciso ler apenas os 3 últimos caracteres de um char. 
Como o tamanho desse `char` pode variar, fiz da seguinte forma:

```
memcpy(valor_final, string_total[strlen(string_total - 3)], 3);
```

onde `valor_final`  agrupará os 3 últimos caracteres e `string_total` é o meu `char` todo.

Porém isso está me retornando os três primeiros. Alguém consegue me apontar o erro?

Answer (score 1):

Tens erro no cálculo

```
memcpy(valor_final,  string_total[strlen(string_total - 3)], 3);
//                  v                                v   ^   |
memcpy(valor_final, @string_total[strlen(string_total) - 3], 4);
```

Não te esqueças de copiar o terminador (`'\0'`). Certifica-te que tens espaço em `valor_final`.